# Javascript code to add products on mouse click

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, angularjs, node.js

I'm here because I would like to embed in my website a little functionality that - I think - it might be done with Javascript.

Here's basically what I'd like to do: my website sells remote vegetable gardens. Meaning that the user can get a small portion of a garden, and plant whatever it is they want to plant (tomatos, potatoes, etc.)
and then, after X months, they get the vegetables deliered to their homes.

I was creating the website with PHP, HTML and CSS. I must say that I'm new to Javascript, I only have some basics but never really used it.

The thing is I would like to make the whole "garden creation" thing more interactive. Meaning that when the user clicks on a vegetable and adds it to the garden, the vegetable will actually appear on a "garden".

So, given that I can make the garden in HTML / CSS, I think I need Javascript to make the vegetables appear on it when I click on them.
Of course the garden will ahve to be filled from start to finish.

What I am asking here is: what do I need to learn in order to do all that? Any specific Javascript function? Do I need jQuery or Ajax?
Please let me know. I'm new to all this JS world but I would like to learn.
Thanks!

Comment: I would suggest learning JS from the startup as here we can only provide you with resources to learn JS. Here is one to get started: http://www.codecademy.com/tracks/javascript, Code Academy seems to do a good job with teaching JavaScript.

Comment: Of course, if there is out there something similar to what I'm trying to do, please send a link so I can check it out and learn from that! ;)

Comment: Thank you Sam, I am already learning on Code Academy. Do you reckon that with that course I have all the info that I need to implement this functionality on my website?